# How to load BLOB files from Oracle to Snowflake and download them from there

Tags: oracle, binary, migration, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, blob

I have BLOB files (pdfs) on Oracle and I'm trying to migrate them all to Snowflake.
My goal is to be able to download the BLOB files (that would be the VARBINARY then) from Snowflake directly instead of just having the hex code.
I understand I'd need a Amazon S3 bucket or any blob storage but still, how from Snowflake could I have access to the pdf files as it is column-based relational database?
How would I do it?

Thank you

Comment: You might want to instead look at how Snowflake handles unstructured data.  This would allow you to securely store the data in blob, rather than in a field in a table.  https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/unstructured.html

Comment: thank you @MikeWalton, I checked with AWS and there are indeed a few solutions (ACL, AWS organizations) but I'll definitely have a look at how snowflake manages unstructured data if that allows me to not go around. thank you

Comment: In addition, storing as unstructured data avoids the VARBINARY column size limitation of 8mb in Snowflake.